# What is the name of that metal stripe, which holds PCI cards?

Tags: pci, terminology, chassis

What is the name of that metal stripe, which holds PCI cards?

[image]

Comment: PCI slot cover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called [brackets](https://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/Brackets-Computer-Mounting/Computer-Brackets-PC-Card/id/427) when attached to an expansion card.

When used by themselves to simply cover an expansion slot in a computer's case, they are often called slot covers.

Comment: I know the empty ones that just cover a slot as blanking plates, not slot covers.

Comment: @MikeScott Ive heard them called a few different names when just covering a slot, but slot covers what I hear the most.